# mvc post with ajax effect

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Before I ask the question, please see the google science fair website for reference: https://www.googlesciencefair.com/en/2013/

In that site, when I click a button, it posts to a different page. I say this because:

- there is a new URL
- the refresh / stop browser button flicks

However, the visual effect looks like an ajax call only. I say this because:

- only the relevant section gets updated
- the header, sidebar, or maybe even the footer does not seem to get reloaded
- the new content just "slides" in

Is there any way to achieve the same effect using ASP.NET MVC 3?

Thanks!

### EDIT

I know how to make ajax calls and get the result. However, when I do this the URL does not change. I want to know to make an ajax call and at the same time change the URL, like the google science fair site does.

Comment: I don't think you will find a framework for public use resembling the one Google used. Their Engineers write their own tools. That's why it's so fascinating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers. The ultimate answer is that they are using [Angular JS](http://angularjs.org/) to achieve the desired effects.

Answer (score 1):

If you run it with dev tools attached and look at the network requests, it shure looks like its making ajax calls

[image]

Comment: Most of the tiles sessms to be covered by <a>. If you use **<a href="#/test" onclick="alert('your ajax');" >Test</a>**, it would change the address @the title and execute any command, including ajax